# How to match a colon after a close bracket

Tags: tcl, expect

Why does the following not match the :

```
expect {
    timeout {puts timedout\n}
    \[1\]: {puts matched\n}
}


> expect test.tcl
[1]:
timedout
```

If I change it and remove the colon the match works:

`expect {
    timeout {puts timedout\n}
    \[1\] {puts matched\n}
}`

`$ expect test.tcl
[1]
matched`

Or if I get rid of the 1st bracket

`expect {
    timeout {puts timedout\n}
    1\]: {puts matched\n}
}`

then it matches:

`$ expect test.tcl
1]:
matched`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the problem with `:`, but with `[`.

The `[` is special to both `Tcl` and the `Expect` pattern matcher so it is particularly messy. To match a literal `[`, you have to backslash once from `Tcl` and then again so that it is not treated as a range during pattern matching. The first backslash, of course, has to be backslashed to prevent it from turning the next backslash into a literal backslash!

```
expect "\\\[" ; #matches literal '['
```

So, your code should be,

```
expect {
    timeout {puts timedout\n}
    \\\[1]: {puts matched\n}
}
```

You can prefix the `]` with a backslash if it makes you feel good, but it is not
necessary. Since there is no matching left-hand bracket to be matched within the
double-quoted string, nothing special happens with the right-hand bracket. It stands for itself and is passed on to the `Expect` command, where it is then interpreted as the end of the range.

The next set of examples shows the behavior of `[` as a pattern preceded by differing numbers of backslashes. If the `[` is not prefixed by a backslash, `Tcl` interprets whatever follows as a command. For these examples, imagine that there is a procedure named `XY` that returns the string `n*w`.

```
expect" [XY]" ; # matches n followed by anything
expect "\[XY]" ; # matches X or Y
expect "\\[XY]" ; # matches n followed by anything followed by w
expect "\\\[XY]" ; # matches [XYl
expect "\\\\[XY]" ; # matches \ followed by n followed ...
expect "\\\\\[XY]" ; # matches sequence of \ and X or Y
```

The  `\\[XY]` case deserves close scrutiny. `Tcl` interprets the first backslash to mean that the second is a literal character. `Tcl` then produces `n*w` as the result of the XY command. The pattern matcher ultimately sees the four character string `n*w`. The pattern matcher interprets this in the usual way. The backslash indicates that the `n` is to be matched literally (which it would even without the backslash since the n is not special to the pattern matcher).

**Source** : [Exploring Expect](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize there were 2 levels of indirection at work. Was only expecting one...

Answer (score 1):

The patterns that worked for me:

- `-exact {[1]:}`
- `-exact "\[1]:"`
- `{\[1]:}`
- `"\\\[1]:"`